# relpace a substring if it matches a particular format?

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

In my app, i get a list of strings as a response to the http request. In those strings, some strings may contain a html tag at the beginning. The format of the string is like this `<span class="qtO">String`. I want to replace the `<span>` part. But, the `qtO` part of the string can be anything. It can be qt1, qt2.., qtA, qtB..,qta, qtb.. etc. Thats why i decided to use the Regex. I new to this and I set the pattern string like this:

```
 String regex = '<span class=\"[a-z]{1}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}\"';`
```

I dont know if it is right. I use the following code to test:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(rTitle);
if (m.find()) {
    System.debug('TITLE: ' + rTitle);
}
```

But, the code is not entering into the `if` block. I am pretty sure that the pattern string is wrong. So, what modifications i have to do to make the pattern string right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I replaced the pattern string from `'<span class=\"[a-z]{1}[a-z]{1}[A-Z]{1}\"'` to `'<span class=\"qt[a-zA-Z0-9]{1}\">'` and now it works fine. It took a little bit of time for me to understand how Regex works.